# How to set Twitch TV channel title

Tags: c#, api, curl, restsharp, twitch

I am working on being able to have my custom chat bot to update my primary channel's title (status). I am following [this](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/how-to-set-title/390) post and I am trying to get the `access_token` from the `REDIRECT_URI`.

The URI that contains the redirect is:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=channel_editor
```

I have manually tested this with my `CLIENT_ID` and `REDIRECT_URI` set to `http://localhost` and I get this response from the above URI (which is what I want):

```
http://localhost/#access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=channel_editor
```

I am trying to get the `access_token` from this URI, but I cant seem to get to it from the code below. My response is:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authenticate?action=authorize&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&scope=channel_editor
```

**Code:**

```
string clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
string redirectURL = "http://localhost";

string url = string.Format("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope=channel_editor",
                 clientID, redirectURL);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string redirUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
response.Close();

// Show the redirected url
Console.WriteLine("You're being redirected to: " + redirUrl);
```

This is a console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This twitch dev post](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/how-to-set-title/390/2) helped me out until I got to the "Make the request" step. My problem was I needed to make the C# equivalent of this cURL command to change the channel's title:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' 
     -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' 
     -d "channel[status]=New+Status!&channel[game]=New+Game!" 
     -X PUT https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/CHANNEL
```

---

**Solution**:

I decided to manually get the `access_token` from the authentication request by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> the token from the URI given below and store it into my database:

```
http://localhost/#access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=channel_editor
```

---

Then, I used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to generate my [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) code with the body request in JSON:

```
string accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/CHANNEL_NAME");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"channel\":{\"status\":\"Hello World\"}}", 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related to c# but implementing it should be easy enough https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/how-to-set-title/390/2

Comment: I actually have a link to that post in the question. I recently found the official documentation for implementing this. I realize that I need to implement this using Auth code and not Implicit Grant. Link is here: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#auth-code

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I did not see that link

Comment: It's all good. I didn't realize how obscure the link is till now.

Comment: I posted my answer to this question. Thank you for leading me to my findings